# Prefrerred channel in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Just setting up our first multichannel campaign. Basically our clients could get messages from their preferred channel Mobile, SMS or Email (default).

I'm currently adding a decision split before each interaction with three options (mobile, SMS, email).

Is this really the common way, or are there any best practices without a need to always create a decision split before each interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Yep - this is the common way, as after your decision you decide what communication activity to send (email, SMS etc)